# Using way-points to create pathway - MATLAB

Tags: google-maps, matlab, navigation

I'm currently working on a map routing system and am not sure if anyone has done this before. I have collected various way-point coordinates on the map using Google map.

How can I create a pathway using the way-points to generate the shortest path?

Comment: Anyone has any idea!!